# How to create a Json string in SAS

Tags: sas

For learning purposes, I am trying to achieve the following

**Scenario:**

We have a decision flow with a node containing a rule flow for checking policyrules. The rules are based on if-else logic where the output for each
rule can be "Decline" or "Review", e.g. "Rule 602: If `customerAge <18 then Decision = 'Decline'`. I have been provided with a table containing an overview of the policy rules.

The columns in the table are:

- RULENUMBER (value: e.g. '602')
- RULELONGDESC (value: string with long description of rule)
- RULESHORTDESC (value: string with short description of rule)
- RULECANBEOVERRULED ( value:Yes/No)
- PRIORITY (value: 1-44)
- DECISION (value: Review/Decline)

When executing the decision flow, we need to send back the output for the policy rules check as a json string. Something very similar to below examples:

```
DeclineDecision=cats(DeclineDecision,'{','"','RuleNumber','"',':','"',DeclineRuleNumber,'"',',','"','RuleText','"',':','"',DeclineRuleText,'"','},');
ReviewDecision=cats(ReviewDecision,'{','"','RuleNumber','"',':','"',ReviewRuleNumber,'"',',','"','RuleText','"',':','"',ReviewRuleText,'"','},');

ReviewDecision=substr(ReviewDecision,1,length(ReviewDecision)-1);
DeclineDecision=substr(DeclineDecision,1,length(DeclineDecision)-1);
```

**Exercise:**
Write a program to create a JsonString.

My starting point is the policy rule table. From that I need to create a macro block where I subset the table based on policy rules and loop over using an array to create the json string.

**Table**
Below is the subsetted table where I need to concatenate all values for each of the three rules in one json string like in the examples above. Press link for picture

[ruletable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfbTD.png)

```
data policytable;
    infile datalines dlm=',';
    length rulelongdesc ruleshortdesc rulecanbeoverrulled $20. priority 8. decision $12.;
    input rulenumber rulelongdesc$ ruleshortdesc$ rulecanbeoverrulled$ priority decision$;
    datalines;
610,False Application,False,Yes,1,Review
602,Age < 18,Alder,No,1,Decline
639,Unknown address,Adresse,Yes,8,Decline
;
run;
```

I have gotten this far. How should I go forward to solve this task? More specifically, how do I set up the do while loop to create the string? For now, it is enough to output the json string with the %put-statement.
Do I use cats() or catx()function?substr()function?

```
 %let PolicyString = (602,610,639);
 %macro json;
 /*subsetting data based on rule number (policy string)*/
 data work.testtable (replace=yes);
 set work.policytable;
 where rulenumber in &PolicyString;
 run;
 /*use do loop to create json string*/
 %local i;
 %let i=1;

 %do %while(&i<4);
 %put i = &i;
 %let i = %eval(&i+1);
 %end;


 %mend;

 %json;
```

Comment: To clarify what you need you should show some example source data and the JSON string(s) you want to generate from that data.

Comment: Hi Tom,

Thanks for the advice. I have added a picture of the table and pasted in my program which I have written so far.

Comment: Hi Rokob - what you're doing has many solutions, none of them particularly like what you're showing though.  Can you explain why you are trying to use the macro language at all here?  What's the final goal, and what will the JSON be - is it going to be put in a text file, or will it be streamed over HTTP, or something else?  So far it's not clear why you can't use PROC JSON for example to write out JSON, why do you want to do it manually?

Comment: Hi Joe - I was asked to do it this way. After doing that, I will enhance the program. Yes, the json in the real project is sent back to the calling system as a response variable.

Comment: It would be much easier by writing it out to a temporary file using PROC JSON and then read that back in using, say, a data step and a filename statement. You'll be stuck with a lot of nested cats and substrs if you build it directly.

Comment: Rokob - right now this isn't a good fit for this site the way the question is.  You've put a lot of information in there, but "I was asked to do it this way" doesn't actually get to what I'm getting at here.  Macro programming like you show is *definitely* not the right way to do anything in SAS - unless you have *very specific* needs that seem unlikely.  What are your *actual* requirements?  It's not a matter of enhancing the program, it's a matter of what you're supposed to do.  Do you need a macro variable to contain a JSON string? Or a data set variable containing a JSON string??

Comment: Joe - I will try to explain it better so that you understand what I need to do. So, I need to create a data process node in our decision flow that recieves 2 input variables from an upstream business rule node. The 2 input variables are concatenated strings containing only the rule number for every rule set in the upstream business rule node. I have a reference table containing details about each rule, which I need to use to create a long json string and send it back to the calling system as a response. Forget what I said about ..told to do it this way and macros. Proc json seems to be the way

Comment: Stu - Thank you. I tried it and it gives me the output I need. Now I need the tweak it a bit so that I can meet all the requirements. Take a look at the comment above which I wrote to Joe. Hope that explanation gives you a better understanding of what I need to do.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `proc json`, you can write your string out to a temporary location, then read it back in as a macro variable that holds one long string. For example:

```
%let PolicyString = (602,610,639);

filename tmp temp;

proc json out=tmp nopretty nosastags;
    export policytable(where=(rulenumber IN &PolicyString.) );
run;

data _null_;
    infile tmp;
    input;
    call symputx('decision_json', _INFILE_);
run;

%put &decision_json.;
```

Output:

```
[{"rulenumber":610,"rulelongdesc":"False Application","ruleshortdesc":"False", ... }]
```

If your columns need to be specific names or in a certain order, you can first create a dataset that has the required column names and order, then pass it to `proc json`.

Keep in mind, macro variables hold up to 65,534 characters. If you don't expect your string to ever get near this amount, you don't need to worry about it. If you do, you'll need to account for that by either splitting up the string or leaving your JSON payload in an external text file and sending it out via another method like `proc http`.

Comment: Or, use `proc lua` which has no limit (other than memory available).  Example of a lua script to ingest JSON:  https://core.sasjs.io/ml__json_8sas.html